# object configured by another class

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, symfony

Below I describe what I'm trying to do and how I think I will do it. What I'm hoping is that a design pattern exists for using one object to configure another. This would allow me to have a nice generic `Job` class rather than an ever-increasing list of `Job` subclasses.

**If there is such a design pattern, what's it called and how would I apply it to my use case?** I'm using the Symfony framework and working in PHP.

---

Part of my application is a `Task` list for user activities.  UserA creates `Task $task1` and it shows up in the `Task` list. UserB accepts `$task1` which changes the task's state to "accepted"; `UserB` starts `$task1` which changes the task's state to "started"; etc.  I've implemented the preceding as a state machine and it works well.

However, each `Task` carries a `Payload`. The `Payload` has 2 properties:

- `Payload$sop` is an SOP object that contains configuration information.
- `Payload$inputvars` is an array of input vars provided by the `Task` creator.

and a method:

- `makeJob(SOP $sop = null, $inputvars = null)`, a factory method that creates a `Job` object configured according to the `SOP` object. This is the "and magic happens" spot in my code.

When `$task1->status` changes to "started", `$task1->payload->makeJob()` is called and a new `Job $job` is created. UserB will interact with a form to input fields required by the `SOP` that produced `$job`. When UserB changes `$job->status` to "completed", the state of the `$task1` will also be changed to "completed".

---

So, is this a reasonable way to reduce subclassing of `Job`? Is there a more efficient way, given the large number of possible `Job` subclasses (we're talking hundreds here).

Comment: What varies between different `Job` instances?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, a Job might be "run an NMR experiment" which would require input sample type, input volume, output trace file (which would be parsed based on it being an NMR experiment), or "run a time|concentration course experiment for enzymeY against substanceX" which would require size of time steps, size of concentration steps, range of time and concentration, etc.

Comment: I prefer your factory method approach.  If you have a lot of common functionality, perhaps you can inherit from a class that contains that common functionality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I considered instantiating a specific `Job` subclass based on an `SOP` template, but that would mean that I'd need hard-coded `Job` subclasses (e.g. NMRJob, TimeCourseJob, etc.), one for each possible `SOP`. But `SOP` is generic- a user will define an SOP using a form. He will pick input types from a list and set validation rules for each one. He will pick output types from a list. His choices will be saved to a database. What I'd like is to have *one* `Job` class with dynamic properties based on the content of the chosen `SOP`.

Comment: Are you just transferring data, or is there behavior in each of these classes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey : `Job` has common behaviours regardless of its data. Each datum would associated with a particular `Job` would  have associated validation behaviour config'd from the `SOP`. I suppose I could just let `Job` have 2 array properties, an $input array and an $output array. Each of those arrays might hold a set of `Rule` objects (generated from the `SOP` config) that would know how to process themselves. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: hmmm... create a factory that takes a list of "steps" to be accomplished, in order. The factory returns a list of delegates corresponding to the "steps" received. This collection of ordered delegates constitutes a "job". For structure/ organization sake you may have an abstract factory,  instantiating a concrete  factory for each category or type of job.